# Javascript recursion without conditional

Tags: javascript, recursion, arrow-functions, lambda-calculus

I'm trying to 'implement' [Church's encoding of lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding) in Javascript, but started having trouble when I wrote the factorial function:

```
const factorial = n => (iszero(n))(ONE)(multiply(n)(factorial(predecessor(n))));
```

`iszero(n)` acts as a conditional, and returns a function that executes it's first parameter if `n` is zero, or the second if it isn't.

Calling this function on any value results in a stack overflow.

I tried to simplify it to find out why:

```
//const ifelse = condition => a => b => condition ? a : b;
//const factorial = n => ifelse(n == 0)(1)(n * factorial(n - 1));
const ifelse = function(condition, a, b) {
    if (condition) {
        return a;
    } else {
        return b;
    }
}
const factorial = function(number) {
    return ifelse(number == 0, 1, number * factorial(number - 1));
}
```

calling factorial here also results in overflow, although if we reduce the `ifelse` function in `factorial`, it makes a perfectly functional factorial function that doesn't throw:

```
//const factorial = n => (n == 0) ? (1) : (n * factorial(n - 1));
const factorial = function(number) {
    if (number == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return number * factorial(number - 1);
    }
}
```

But I'm trying to use nothing but functions inside the factorial, so the ternary conditional operator is not acceptable (see the commented arrow notation).

**Why is my `factorial` function resulting in a stack overflow when invoked on any value, and can this be avoided while still using only functions (no conditionals)?**

**EDIT**: the definitions for the first piece of code:

```
const TRUE = x => y => x;
const FALSE = x => y => y;

const ZERO = f => x => x;
const ONE = f => x => f(x);

const pair = a => b => f => f(a)(b);

const first = p => p(TRUE);
const second = p => p(FALSE);

const iszero = n => n(x => FALSE)(TRUE);

const successor = n => f => x => f(n(f)(x));
const multiply = n1 => n2 => f => x => n1(n2(f))(x);
const predecessor = n => second(n(p => pair(successor(first(p)))(first(p)))(pair(ZERO)(ZERO)));
```

Comment: please add the missing parts as well.

Comment: Wow this reads terrible. No wonder you get confused. Why do you write it like this, is there a specific reason?

Comment: I really don't know how to write it better, can you edit it or point out what's unclear? English isn't my first language so my writing comes off a bit weird. I added the second piece of code to avoid including the missing parts of the first one, cause there's a lot of them.

Comment: You get SO error because you have all functions in your stack till it reaches to zero condition. And you have conditional operator in your code.

Comment: I ment the code itself. It is hard to understand. Using a 'normal' function with a few if/else's are so much easier to read, and often more maintainable. Your english is fine :)

Comment: @Martijn You've never seen [Unlambda](http://www.madore.org/~david/programs/unlambda/#what_looks), I presume. :)

Comment: Nope. Makes it a little more clear. Though (in my quick read) doesn't explain *why* you want this. But maybe it's because I've learned traditional :p

Comment: @Martijn In my personal opinion, using the short arrow form is more readable because it includes less 'junk'. It only includes the information you need in as short a sentence as possible, but hey that's just my opinion :P I'll change them to traditional in a moment.

Comment: I rather think he meant that `const ONE = 1` makes sense, and `const ONE = f => x => f(x)` does not :P Arrow functions are indeed way more readable if you're going to do what you're doing. However, I can see his point too - I can't see any practical purpose to Church numerals aside from being a math toy. :)

Comment: But math toys are fun to play with ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting stack overflow because JavaScript is not a lazy-evaluated language. For example:

```
ifelse(false)(console.log("YES"))(console.log("NO"))
// => YES
//    NO
```

Both parameters are evaluated. The way to keep that from happening is to keep them as functions till you need them.

```
ifelse(false)(() => console.log("YES"))(() => console.log("NO"))()
// => NO
```

So in your second `factorial` definition, `factorial(n - 1)` is getting executed no matter what; `ifelse` is just there to let you select which of the two values to return. Obviously, `factorial(0)` will then call `factorial(-1)`, which will continue right down to -infinity, as limited by memory.

Keeping them unevaluated:

```
factorial = n => ifelse(n == 0)(() => 1)(() => n * factorial(n - 1)())
factorial(1)()
# => 1
factorial(5)()
// => 120
```

I can't tell you what's wrong with your first set given that you don't have the definitions, but the cause is likely the same.

EDIT: Having seen the definitions... let me first add one of my own:

```
const display = n => n(x => x + 1)(0)
```

(The `n(x => x + 1)(0)` is a handy trick to convert Church numerals to normal numbers, so we can see what's happening. Debug tool only, so it shouldn't violate the purity of what you're doing.)

With our inspector at hand... the `predecessor` is not correct. See:

```
display(successor(predecessor(ONE)))
// => TypeError: f(...) is not a function
//        at f (repl:1:33)
//        at x (repl:1:36)
```

Try this (direct from your Wikipedia link):

```
const predecessor = n => f => x => n(g => h => h(g(f)))(u => x)(u => u)
```

With that in place, you get the correct result:

```
display(successor(predecessor(ONE)))
// => 1
```

Now, to turn to the factorial. Applying the same trick as above (wrapping the `if` and `else` branches into closures to keep them from premature evaluation):

```
const factorial = n => (iszero(n))(() => ONE)(() => multiply(n)(factorial(predecessor(n))()));

const FIVE = successor(successor(successor(successor(ONE))));
display(factorial(FIVE)())
// => 120
```

Comment: Fascinating! And you're absolutely right, the issue with my `predecessor` is using a comma in `pair(ZERO, ZERO)`, instead it should be `pair(ZERO)(ZERO)`, I'll correct it in a moment. This pred method with pairs comes from [this paper](https://www21.in.tum.de/~eberlm//lambda_paper.pdf) btw, i found it more intuitive than the Wikipedia method.But hey great answer thanks again!

Comment: Oh, I should have noticed that. But yeah, wasn't really the point of the question so I didn't waste too much time on it, just copied a definition known to work. :P

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that function arguments are evaluated completely before the function itself is run. So, for example, when

```
(n * factorial(n - 1))
```

is an argument list, that code there *must* resolve to a value before proceeding to call the function returned by

```
n => ifelse(n == 0)(1)
```

It doesn't first check your `ifelse` condition before evaluating - it tries to evaluate it no matter what. So, a stack overflow results, because it attempts to continually figure out the `else` result of `n`, then `n - 1`, then `n - 2`, ... `n - 10`, `n - 11`, and so on.

Pass `b` as a *function* instead, so that you can call it and evaluate the `else` to a value only if the condition ends up being `false`:

```js
const ifelse = condition => a => b => condition ? a : b();
const factorial = n => ifelse(n == 0)(1)(() => n * factorial(n - 1));
//                                       ^^^^^
console.log(factorial(5));
```

Comment: This wont get SO for input 5 of course, try it with 40000.

Comment: The problem was his previous code *was* getting a SO even with low inputs.